# Sqlite "word only" search

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to implement a "word only" search in sqlite.

My first option seems to be [charlist] that select words that are surrounded by [space, tab, point, comma, punctuation, etc].
Something like this: `SELECT ... WHERE 'name' LIKE "%[ \t.,!?]word[ \t.,!?]%"`

However I cannot find a way to add space/tab to [charlist]. 
Is this possible ?

What is "the best way" to implement a "word only" search in sql ?

Answer (score 1):

Like does not support character classes, but [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) does.

However, searching for words is what the [full-text search extension](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) has been designed for.